# Can a project be open source even if you don't have a license?

Tags: unlicensed-code

Suppose I am working on a project. I publish this project on a website. I release it without a copyright notice OR a licence. But in the project title /description I say it is open source.

**My question:**

Under these circumstances is the project open sourced?

- If yes, under what conditions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### No.

You can *claim* it's open source, but it wouldn't be true. If you don't declare under what agreement people can use the work, or what rights they have, they should legally assume they have no rights (i.e. it is entirely your copyright).

The fact that you haven't included a copyright notice doesn't matter: a CN is a nicety which is in fact there to remind people of the fact that it belongs to you and you can't use it in any way not allowed by the license. The Lack of a CN doesn't remove your copyright.

Answer (score 0):

As ArtOfCode said, not choosing a License will make it copyrighted. But, if you don't want to choose a specific license, you may choose to [unlicense](http://choosealicense.com/licenses/unlicense/) your project, which will make it public domain.

Comment: This is still a license.

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher I don't see any reasoning for a down vote. It still answers the question, and provides an alternative.

Comment: If the wording is changed to indicate that this is a license, then I will revert that downvote. Right now, the answer is misleading.